# multiple selected items in listview stay highlighted android

Tags: android, listview

So, What I have done is when I click on listview item, it turns to grey. But when I select another item from the listview then the previous highlighted grey item turns to default and new item turns to grey.

What I want is to stay both of them to be highlighted, and when a click on the highlighted items they should turn back to normal as well.

Here is my code:

**My ListView XML**

```
    <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/selector"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/group_name"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/group_name" />
```

**My Color.xml**

```
    <color name="list_pressed">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="list_default">#d3d3d3</color>
```

**My selector.xml**

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Selected Item -->
<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@color/list_pressed" />

<!-- Default Item -->
<item
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@color/list_default" />
 </selector>
```

**Onclick Listner**

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            view.setSelected(true);

            GroupList clickedGroup = mygroupList.get(position);
            String message = " you clicked name " + position + " and name is " + clickedGroup.getname();
            Toast.makeText(addgroups.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Waiting for help and thanks in advance.

Edited:
**Here is my listAdapter**

```
 private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GroupList>
 {
    public MyListAdapter()
    {
        super(addgroups.this, R.layout.grouplist, mygroupList);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView == null)
        {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grouplist, parent, false);
        }

        //find the contact to work
        GroupList currentgroup =  mygroupList.get(position);

        TextView contactname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
        contactname.setText(currentgroup.getname());

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add);
        imageView.setImageResource(currentgroup.getimg());

        return  itemView;
        //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep a list of highlighted items in the Adapter.

Comment: @shark thanks alot for instant reply. Can you provide me some code for that? or some little more detail to achieve that?

Comment: You are using listSelector which work like this only. The behaviour that you want is achievable by setting setSelected property to background property of you list cell layout.You have to create an local ArrayList to keep the state of each cell, so that you again set the state of background cell if get recycled

Comment: @SagarTrehanThanks alot for the hint. Problem solved!